# Cross-referencing panel-tabset in Quarto

Tags: quarto, cross-reference

Is there a way of cross-referencing tabs names in panel-tabset in Quarto?

I have tried with section but it doesn't work.

```
::: panel-tabset

## A {#sec-inst1}

## B {#sec-inst2}

:::

If a then see @sec-inst1 else see @sec-inst2
```

Comment: Related, though not quite a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66246651/8770170